# Create Maui Workload Offline Installer

Tags: maui

Im trying to make maui workload offline installer for my publish server.

What ive done so far is to make offline cache of installed package in my pre production server like

this :

First ive run this :
 `dotnet workload install maui-android`

and make a copy of workload folder :

[image: workload cahce]

the ive made this script for installing them on production server :

```
`msiexec.exe /i 1_microsoft.net.sdk.android.manifest-8.0.100.msi.x64\34.0.43\f0a38d69b91da2c9cf4812140d614380-x64.msi /QN /L*V "1_microsoft.net.sdk.android.manifest-8.0.100.msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 2_microsoft.net.sdk.ios.manifest-8.0.100.msi.x64\17.0.8478\ef05a2a0a7cab4628b9a106ebdf303e5-x64.msi /QN /L*V "2_microsoft.net.sdk.ios.manifest-8.0.100.msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 3_microsoft.net.sdk.maccatalyst.manifest-8.0.100.msi.x64\17.0.8478\28c86dc0e8d71959057ea0317b3698a3-x64.msi /QN /L*V "3_microsoft.net.sdk.maccatalyst.manifest-8.0.100.msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 4_microsoft.net.sdk.macos.manifest-8.0.100.msi.x64\14.0.8478\4ab27be2a7a2a677d46caf9075f2248d-x64.msi /QN /L*V "4_microsoft.net.sdk.macos.manifest-8.0.100.msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 5_microsoft.net.sdk.maui.manifest-8.0.100.msi.x64\8.0.3\24bb901c0e890ef24f6b95928cd093a1-x64.msi /QN /L*V "5_microsoft.net.sdk.maui.manifest-8.0.100.msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 6_microsoft.net.sdk.tvos.manifest-8.0.100.msi.x64\17.0.8478\fbafa6938113eb2095e12092037bd5fe-x64.msi /QN /L*V "6_microsoft.net.sdk.tvos.manifest-8.0.100.msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 7_microsoft.net.sdk.aspire.manifest-8.0.100.msi.x64\8.0.0-preview.1.23557.2\729ebc3a4ae248c9d9e33c8304329ec3-x64.msi /QN /L*V "7_microsoft.net.sdk.aspire.manifest-8.0.100.msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 8_Microsoft.Maui.Sdk.Msi.x64\8.0.3\f2e062aa6de7c87c376aca631ea3d8c1-x64.msi /QN /L*V "8_Microsoft.Maui.Sdk.Msi.x64.8.0.3.log"

msiexec.exe /i 8_Microsoft.Maui.Sdk.Msi.x64\7.0.101\1e65e70e85ef115e49e3f056978b44d4-x64.msi /QN /L*V "8_1_Microsoft.Maui.Sdk.Msi.x64.7.0.101.log"

msiexec.exe /i 9_Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Msi.x64\8.0.3\42c7e7ac710238fa82a95c6bbdacded3-x64.msi /QN /L*V "9_Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 10_Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.Msi.x64\8.0.3\0ada47a53b75853a2c93db87305e93ae-x64.msi /QN /L*V "10_Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 11_Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.Sdk.Msi.x64\7.0.101\cf46a8bc30e486b0a084b2f475a442ab-x64.msi /QN /L*V "11_Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.Sdk.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 12_Microsoft.Maui.Templates.net8.Msi.x64\8.0.3\ed27f1f4c4d722a8a44d78d012531c21-x64.msi /QN /L*V "12_Microsoft.Maui.Templates.net8.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 13_Microsoft.Maui.Templates.net7.Msi.x64\7.0.101\c794a8bd35a038b71978aeec738d3e84-x64.msi /QN /L*V "13_Microsoft.Maui.Templates.net7.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 14_Microsoft.Maui.Core.Msi.x64\8.0.3\7b73c8818ede0e18c1a0f33a888371d5-x64.msi /QN /L*V "14_Microsoft.Maui.Core.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 15_Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Msi.x64\8.0.3\bd2f00793336843ffa5f8d4d239635dc-x64.msi /QN /L*V "15_Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 16_Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Build.Tasks.Msi.x64\8.0.3\9bb9cc9144b855db44f5690cb40f88df-x64.msi /QN /L*V "16_Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Build.Tasks.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 17_Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Core.Msi.x64\8.0.3\91a357d26bcf660e6ae8f94d2cd086f5-x64.msi /QN /L*V "17_Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Core.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 18_Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Msi.x64\8.0.3\939e76bdea65ca880a6e9eda0a52738f-x64.msi /QN /L*V "18_Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 19_Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Msi.x64\8.0.3\40ec93ff21587846da847cbd2c86dc53-x64.msi /QN /L*V "19_Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 20_Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Msi.x64\8.0.3\1ea8a83e2db632ef4a88132ca82f3c04-x64.msi /QN /L*V "20_Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 21_Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows.Msi.x64\34.0.43\f9b4db869751089e33a7aac8dc754188-x64.msi /QN /L*V "21_Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 21_Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows.Msi.x64\33.0.95\60f0e13cf49938e11638e841420111cc-x64.msi /QN /L*V "21_1_Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 22_Microsoft.Android.Ref.34.Msi.x64\34.0.43\14c39505d76e9c027c5e842b078534c4-x64.msi /QN /L*V "22_Microsoft.Android.Ref.34.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 23_Microsoft.Android.Runtime.34.android-arm.Msi.x64\34.0.43\6c92ee49816f84588e259e4df6cf120c-x64.msi /QN /L*V "23_Microsoft.Android.Runtime.34.android-arm.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 24_Microsoft.Android.Runtime.34.android-arm64.Msi.x64\34.0.43\b4953f2e2a2d743585e51140f317e490-x64.msi /QN /L*V "24_Microsoft.Android.Runtime.34.android-arm64.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 25_Microsoft.Android.Runtime.34.android-x86.Msi.x64\34.0.43\edde431916e280e50a177a624b930568-x64.msi /QN /L*V "25_Microsoft.Android.Runtime.34.android-x86.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 26_Microsoft.Android.Runtime.34.android-x64.Msi.x64\34.0.43\9e83ba0aaed8901a6e2aa71974e82826-x64.msi /QN /L*V "26_Microsoft.Android.Runtime.34.android-x64.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 27_Microsoft.Android.Templates.Msi.x64\34.0.43\342a2ac8aade1c3c37f3a6f9feb3a650-x64.msi /QN /L*V "27_Microsoft.Android.Templates.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 28_Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-arm.Msi.x64\7.0.14\Microsoft.Mono.android-arm.7.0.14-x64.msi /QN /L*V "28_Microsoft.Mono.android-arm.7.0.14-x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 29_Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-arm64.Msi.x64\7.0.14\Microsoft.Mono.android-arm64.7.0.14-x64.msi /QN /L*V "29_Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-arm64.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 30_Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-x64.Msi.x64\7.0.14\Microsoft.Mono.android-x64.7.0.14-x64.msi /QN /L*V "30_Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-x64.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 31_Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-x86.Msi.x64\7.0.14\Microsoft.Mono.android-x86.7.0.14-x64.msi /QN /L*V "31_Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-x86.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 32_Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoAOTCompiler.Task.Msi.x64\7.0.14\Microsoft.MonoAOTCompiler.Task.7.0.14-x64.msi /QN /L*V "32_Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoAOTCompiler.Task.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 33_Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoTargets.Sdk.Msi.x64\7.0.14\Microsoft.MonoTargets.Sdk.7.0.14-x64.msi /QN /L*V "33_Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoTargets.Sdk.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 34_Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.win-x64.Cross.android-x86.Msi.x64\7.0.14\Microsoft.AOT.win-x64.Cross.android-x86.7.0.14-x64.msi /QN /L*V "34_Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.win-x64.Cross.android-x86.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 35_Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.win-x64.Cross.android-x64.Msi.x64\7.0.14\Microsoft.AOT.win-x64.Cross.android-x64.7.0.14-x64.msi /QN /L*V "35_Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.win-x64.Cross.android-x64.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 36_Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.win-x64.Cross.android-arm.Msi.x64\7.0.14\Microsoft.AOT.win-x64.Cross.android-arm.7.0.14-x64.msi /QN /L*V "36_Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.win-x64.Cross.android-arm.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 37_Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.win-x64.Cross.android-arm64.Msi.x64\7.0.14\Microsoft.AOT.win-x64.Cross.android-arm64.7.0.14-x64.msi /QN /L*V "37_Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.win-x64.Cross.android-arm64.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 39_Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-arm64.Msi.x64\8.0.0\c35e45c64d084db6f85c270362874f29-x64.msi /QN /L*V "39_Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-arm64.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 40_Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-x64.Msi.x64\8.0.0\da3211aa69e841a7218a98b1f8e63003-x64.msi /QN /L*V "40_Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-x64.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 41_Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-x86.Msi.x64\8.0.0\9446aa48b9673fa5d911cb4eaa5a903d-x64.msi /QN /L*V "41_Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-x86.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 42_Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoAOTCompiler.Task.Msi.x64\8.0.0\bd65aaaf4ee8517ca1226acc213ff702-x64.msi /QN /L*V "42_Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoAOTCompiler.Task.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 43_Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoTargets.Sdk.Msi.x64\8.0.0\19417a1e99d488d094537d910c54205d-x64.msi /QN /L*V "43_Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoTargets.Sdk.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 44_Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.win-x64.Cross.android-x86.Msi.x64\8.0.0\ac0104188804102f1cb1a872d6fccfdc-x64.msi /QN /L*V "44_Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.win-x64.Cross.android-x86.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 45_Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.win-x64.Cross.android-x64.Msi.x64\8.0.0\c9fbd7e50943797ea6143598ed3c4383-x64.msi /QN /L*V "45_Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.win-x64.Cross.android-x64.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 46_Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.win-x64.Cross.android-arm.Msi.x64\8.0.0\27b446b777945024db1b5896ef85eaed-x64.msi /QN /L*V "46_Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.win-x64.Cross.android-arm.Msi.x64.log"

msiexec.exe /i 47_Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.win-x64.Cross.android-arm64.Msi.x64\8.0.0\b810b1ce6d5f8a759f38e74ae97868fb-x64.msi /QN /L*V "47_Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.win-x64.Cross.android-arm64.Msi.x64.log"`
```

then ive install the .Net8 and JDK11 on server.

and after ive run this command on my root project on server to build apk :

`dotnet publish -f net8.0-android -c Release -p:AndroidSigningKeyStore=0bbd49a34erwf3a0982d15e188ac7f51.keystore  -p:AndroidSigningKeyAlias=1 -p:AndroidSigningKeyPass=sdf3fF32%$ -p:AndroidSigningStorePass=sdf3fF32%$`

ive got this error :

[image]

**btw i dont have any internet connection on production server.

Installing package one by one and still no hope